# Matlab function call directory

Tags: matlab

So i had this issue that occurred when I ran a Matlab script. Here is an a simple example that illustrates it:

So its important to outline the file structure:

```
MainFolder
    script.m
    SubFolder
        a1.csv
        a2.csv
        a3.csv
```

now say i have a script like this:

-> script.m

```
dir
```

it would simply print out the files in the folder.

Now the wierd thing, if i run the script in the Subfolder like this:

```
>>script
```

it will do this:

```
>> a1.csv    a2.csv    a3.csv
```

but if i do this in the folder:

```
>>run('C:\Users\....\MainFolder\script.m')
```

it will only print out

```
>> script.m
```

So obviously it is acting as if i ran it form `MainFolder` rather than `SubFolder`.

What is the point of this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dir` command shows the directory contents of Matlab's current directory, *not* that of where the script is located. So the script showed you the directory contents of wherever you happened to be in the Matlab command prompt when you called that script.

To get what you want, use this in the script:

```
dir(fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')))
```

Comment: Also note that you can use the `cd` command to change the current directory: `cd('new/working/directory')`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pwd` to see current dir

Use `cd` to change directory

Use `path` to see if your project folders are included in the path

Use `which` to see you are calling the right *.m file (in case there is multiple .m files with same name on the path)